# Timing the Browser with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

Objective:  time how long the browser takes loading a page, from the earliest point possible in its loading process, starting as soon as possible after the server has started sending it data.

Context:  new feature to existing set of scripts that stores web performance data.  Most of the existing app is on the server-side, the new feature is for the client side.

This is where I need help.
I am looking for the earliest event to use for a script like this, which is using

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("<?= $baseURL?><?= $pageparts.$common ?>/saveData.php",
            {
              typeOfRecord:"docready",
              thisURL:"<?= $thisURL ?>"
            },
            function(data,status){
              ;
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Here is a screenshot of what results look like.  I am looking for the earliest and lastest events or points in the browser load process, starting from the time it starts receiving data from the server in response to the request it has made.
[image: Timestamps and split times on server and client side of generating a web page.]

[You can run a sample at this link](http://launchpad-001.com/_firingRange/demos/timed-run-so-question-30950820/)

**Here is what I am having a problem figuring out:**

1. What events should be used to record the earliest moment when the browser is receiving and starting to render the page source sent to it by the server, and the last thing done by the browser to be considered loaded.

Comment: If you include jquery.js in the header and follow it immediately with a script element that uses `$.ajax()` *not* wrapped in an event handler then that request should be made early, before the browser even gets to the `<body>` tag... But why don't you use your browser's dev console's network (and other) tab(s) for this?

Comment: I had no idea a browser's dev console does what I am looking for.  I am checking that out.

Comment: Why is this question getting down votes?  I have no idea what the problem is. If I find out the problem, I will remove the problem.

Comment: nnnnnn, one of the requirements is to store the results in a datbase where we track how long things take.  The information visible through the console is great, but I have to get it into a database.  Running the ajax without an event handler is something I had not done before.  I know that sounds dumb, but I just didn't know about that route.

Comment: So the down vote is for this being a dumb question?

Comment: I don't know why somebody downvoted (it wasn't me). So did you try a `$.post()` directly, without an event handler? By the way, I just noticed in the client-side code shown above that you've included two copies of jQuery - do you need to versions for some reason? I'd try to avoid that if you're worried about performance. Also you stated that the above script was for "document ready", but it's not, it's on the window load.

Comment: Yes I did.  It worked perfectly and filled a gap in my understanding. If you post your comment, as answer,  I will approve it.  I am going see if I can make the question better, but already answered it for sure.

Comment: The two copies of jquery are an error, I have removed, them.  Putting up corrected code.  Also changing description to match code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include jquery.js in the header and follow it immediately with a script element that uses `$.ajax()` (or `$.post()` or whatever) *not* wrapped in an event handler, then that ajax request should be made immediately at that point, before the browser even gets to the `<body>` tag.

So assuming the JS code you show is in the header you could add an ajax call just before where you bind the document ready handler.

Note that of course the browser would have to download jQuery before getting to your script, so if you want to get in even before that you'd have to code the ajax call yourself without jQuery methods, in a script element that is included before jQuery.

You may also want to look into using your browser's dev console's network (and other) tab(s) for this type of thing.

Comment: I am running a post using right after the character set meta tag as the first things in the head section.  JQuery still part of that, but I am working on the post without jQuery.  I thought a post like that is Ajax, so there I need to learn about what Ajax is, and why that post is not Ajax.  To get a read on the end of the browser loading, I have another online post after the closing HTML tag, plus a post wrapped by window.ready.

Comment: Does it matter which browser console?  Can the console output be sent to a database?  Is it possible to read the console of a remote browser that is hitting my site?  Can the console be used to see the load times experienced by people using my site?  One of my requirements is to see how long it takes my customers to load my site, which varies a lot, depending on the speed of internet connections and client memory

Comment: JQuery's `$.post()` method does make an ajax request, yes. But being a jQuery method it can't run until after jQuery is loaded. You can make an ajax request without jQuery if you code it yourself - there are any number of tutorials about that online - and then the ajax request wouldn't be delayed until after jQuery downloads. (Regarding the console, it's a client tool, so no, you can't use it to see what your individual customers are experiencing.)